# A generic error occurrs in GDI+ when I try to upload an image

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I get this error when I try to upload an image in my MVC application.
When I started my application on my local computer I don't get this error. It appears only when I deploy my application at hosting.
This is my code for saving an image:

```
if (file.ContentLength < 5242880 && (extension == ".jpg" || extension == ".jpeg")){
         string localFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + extension;
         string pathToSave = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images"), localFileName);
         var relativePath = MakeRelative(pathToSave, Server.MapPath("~"));
         file.SaveAs(pathToSave);
}
```

Then I save path in my db.
The stack trace is:

```
[ExternalException (0x80004005): A generic error occurred in GDI+.]
   System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams) +477384
   System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageFormat format) +69
   System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename) +25
   Marriage_Agency_Women_.Controllers.ApplicationBaseController.CreateThumbnail(String source, Int32 maxSize) +328
   Marriage_Agency_Women_.Controllers.<Edit>d__3.MoveNext() +3938
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +17
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +225
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +129
```

What can be the reason of this error?
Thanks for help!

Comment: Please put your code on `try{} catch()` block and then post the exception.

Comment: Are you aware that this, or a similar, warning, has appeared alongside the documentation for every version of .NET's, [System.Drawing Namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing(v=vs.110).aspx): "Classes within the System.Drawing namespace are not supported for use within a Windows or ASP.NET service. Attempting to use these classes from within one of these application types may produce unexpected problems, such as diminished service performance and run-time exceptions."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my fault. I tried to save thumbnails in the folder that didn't exist. Thanks for help!